# How do I create an OpenApi from a Rest interface?

Tags: spring-boot, pagination, openapi

I would like to map this rest interface in OpenApi?
Is there by chance a tool with which I can create an OpenApi from the rest interface without including this tool in my Spring Boot Application? Or is there a template I can use to build the interface myself in Openapi? I would be very grateful for an approach.

```
@GetMapping("/page")
    public Page<FootballTeamLocationEntityView> getPageableFootballTeamList(@PageableDefault(value = 10) Pageable pageable) {
        return footballTeamService.getFootballTeams(pageable);
    }
```

I use OpenApi 3.0 and Spring Boot 2

**UPDATE 1**

```
   default  ResponseEntity<FootballTeamLocation> getPageableFootballTeamList(Pageable pageable) {
        getRequest().ifPresent(request -> {
            for (MediaType mediaType: MediaType.parseMediaTypes(request.getHeader("Accept"))) {
                if (mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.valueOf("application/json"))) {
                    String exampleString = "{ \"name\" : \"Westfalen-Stadion\", \"locZ\" : 5.962133212312, \"externalId\" : \"externalId\", \"locX\" : 6.02749381870403, \"id\" : 0, \"locY\" : 11.4658129805029452 }";
                    ApiUtil.setExampleResponse(request, "application/json", exampleString);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using **springdoc**. It is a recent library that is easier to use and way less error-prone than Springfox (the other option for Spring Boot apps). We moved to it 2 years ago and we are very glad we did. There is very good documentation and tutorials online for it:

- https://springdoc.org/
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation

It is also very active and you usually get your issues answered very fast on the [github page](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I took your advice and got an OpenApi out (but very badly formatted :D)
The only problem is that the OpenApi does not match my rest interfaces. In Update 1 you can find my Autogenerieten Rest interface.

Comment: OpenApi builds me a rest interface of return type Response Entity where I want to get back the type Page.

Comment: Now I am confused. Wasn't your question about how to get OpenAPI definition for your REST API? Why would you want to auto-generate the REST API based on the OpenAPI definition you just got from your coded REST API?

Comment: Usually, you use OpenAPI definition to generate a client for the REST API or to create stub servers, but I never heard about using it to generate real server-side code. That makes little sense to me.

Comment: Basically, I generate my RestController based on the OpenApi that I create manually. However, with Pagination it did not work and so I went the other way around. I have now thanks to your help from the RestController for the above method me the OpenApi generate.
The method generated from the OpenApi must be overwritten in the RestController so that there is an interface to my service. Or am I wrong there?

Comment: But that is exactly the use case I never heard of or know someone that did it. As I wrote before the usual use case is the following. [1] You implement your REST API. [2] You generate OpenAPI definition based on your implemented REST API (with the help of tools such as springdoc). [3] You use the created OpenAPI definition to either auto-generate a client for your REST API or to auto-generate server stubs that you can use for example for testing purposes. This is the common use case. I never heard someone using OpenAPI definition to auto-generate the actual running code for the REST API.